# A Hausdorff's distance convergence

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $(C_n)_n$ be a sequence of nonempty closed sets of $E$.

Let $C:=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_{n}$. We assume (here) that $C$ is not empty.

Let $d_H$ be the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Do we have $d_H(C,C_n)\underset{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow}0$?

If yes, any idea about why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in general, and not even in finite dimensions! For example, in $\Bbb{R}^2$, consider the following sequences of line segments:
$$C_n = \operatorname{conv}\{(0, 0), (\cos(n), \sin(n))\}.$$
Then $C = \{(0, 0)\}$, but $d_H(C_n, C) = 1$, as $C \subseteq C_n$ and $C_n \subseteq C + B_{\Bbb{R}^2}$ for all $n$.

Comment: What do you mean by conv?

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson Convex hull.